# Add span with bgcolor under link in table cell

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a simple bar like coloring to a table cell.

Sample [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/bisise/1/edit)

HTML

```
 <table class="table table-bordered"> 
    <tr> 
        <td class="cell-bar">
            <span class="bar" style="width:10%"></span>
            <a href="">clickable - half covered</a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

CSS

```
.cell-bar { 
  position:relative;
}
.cell-bar * {
  z-index : 2;
}
.cell-bar>.bar { 
  position: absolute;
  top : 0;
  left : 0;
  bottom : 0;
  border-right : 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  background-color : rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.1);
  z-index : 1;
}
```

I've set the `z-index` for the bar span to 1 and all other children to 2 - But the span is covering the link making it unclickable - any way around this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index` has no effect on non-positioned elements (i.e. the default `position: static`)

You need to add a position to this block:

```
.cell-bar * {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hifalovepali/2/edit)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```css
.cell-bar { 
  position:relative;
}
.cell-bar * {
  z-index : 2;
  position: relative;
}
.cell-bar>.bar { 
  position: absolute;
  top : 0;
  left : 0;
  bottom : 0;
  border-right : 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  background-color : rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.1);
  z-index : 1;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered"> 
    <tr> 
        <td class="cell-bar">
            <span class="bar" style="width:10%"></span>
            <a href="">clickable - half covered</a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

i think you missed to give `position` to `.cell-bar *`